# Call to undefined function wp_create_category()

Tags: wp-cron, wp-insert-post

I’m sorry, I speak a little English.

My custom theme:

~/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/functions.php

```
function mct_task() {
    include( get_template_directory() . '/inc/cron.php' );
}
add_action( 'mct_hook', 'mct_task' );
//
function mytheme_setup_options() {
    if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'mct_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'mct_hook' );
    } else {}
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options' );
```

~/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/inc/cron.php

```
$category_id = wp_create_category( 'Super' );
// $my_post = array( 'post_category'=> array( $category_id ) );
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

~/error_log

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category() in...
```

Why? What is the problem?

I would like use category at wp_insert_post with wp-cron. If the category exists, use the category ID, if not exists, create new category.

Answer (score 0):

The core functions needs to be called within the WordPress environment only. The `cron.php` is out of it thus resulting in that `Call to undefined function` error. Easiest way to the solution of your problem is to move the contents on that file in the `mct_task()` function.

Comment: The wp_insert_post is work in cron.php file (without wp_create_category function) and another WP functions is okay.

Comment: I try the ~/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/functions.php file, the mct_task function, but the error: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category() in...

Comment: I try the ~/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/functions.php file, in first line, but the error: There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions. Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_category() in...